# SQL Delete values including NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete all the records which don't have Remarks as 'Invalid Process' & other 2 conditions as below code :-

```
 DELETE FROM Entry WHERE EmployeeId = 474 AND Entry_Date = '2016-10-01' 
 AND Remarks <> 'Invalid Process'
```

But problem here is it doesn't delete the records which have NULL as value. I want to delete all except Remarks as 'Invalid Process'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `IS NULL` condition. `<>` operator cannot check `NULL` values

```
 DELETE FROM Entry WHERE EmployeeId = 474 AND Entry_Date = '2016-10-01' 
 AND (Remarks <> 'Invalid Process' or Remarks IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the operator '<>' when considering NULL.This behavior is defined in the ANSI SQL-92 standard.

use the standard syntax for checking NULLs - `"IS NULL"`

DELETE FROM Entry WHERE EmployeeId = 474 AND Entry_Date = '2016-10-01' 
 AND ( Remarks IS NULL OR Remarks <> 'Invalid Process')